# C# image distortion

Tags: c#, image, distortion

I know very few about programming in C# and I searched before about this topic here and in google. When I search about how to distort an image most post refer to MagickImage or other libraries, and actually I tried the examples are here, but nothing looks to work for me. I tried with MagickImage, I couldn't make it work, and I post a question about it. Nobody answer, that's why I am making it in a diferent way.

What I want to do is just distort an image as it is in a 3D space, is there a way to do it in C# with out a library? or with a library?

I would greatly appreciate any help on this matter

```
Bitmap processedBitmap = new Bitmap(@"c:\Users\Nicci\Desktop\santa\libro.jpg");
        int width = processedBitmap.Width;
        int height = processedBitmap.Height;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                Color oldPixel = processedBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                Color newPixel = oldPixel;
                processedBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, newPixel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards!

Comment: So you want to do things like arbitrary 3D rotations and such?

Comment: It could be that a picture is worth a thousand words. You might be looking for [Perspective Projection](https://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS791E/Notes/PerspectiveProjection.pdf) (PDF format).

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes Harold. That's exactly what I want to do. Is it very dificult without any library? The think is that I can't get Magick image to work!

Comment: Yeah well I am sorry for the ambiguity. That's what I want Andrew, what Harold said! Do you have some option guys? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not particularly hard to do without libraries, though it takes a bit of code (which I won't all type right now), you just have to

- loop over every pixel of the destination image (yes not the source, you'll see why)
- inverse-transform the destination coordinate to a source coordinate by pre-multiplying it by the inverse transform matrix (sounds fancy but is easy)
- sample the source image at the coordinate found that way, you can use bilinear filtering here for better results (this is part why it's done this way around, also to avoid holes)

To avoid being ridiculously slow (due to GetPixel and SetPixel), lock the bitmaps and use `unsafe` code.

Comment: Harold,

Thanks a lot for your answer. I appreciate the time you are taking to help me. As I said before, I know very very little about c#. So I will try today to write a code based on your advice. Then I will come back here and paste it in case it does not work, so you can assist me... I hope is not a problem

Comment: Well Harold, I have to admit I am completly lost. Do you guys have some idea on where to start? Some tutorial or sample code? :(

Comment: @fauvent start by copying the image pixel by pixel, then put in the matrix multiplication so you copy pixels from a transformed location, be careful not to go outside the image here, then add interpolation or it'll look bad

Comment: Thanks for your time Harold, ok so I came up with this start. It looks like is ok. This would be a good start?

Comment: I worte it in the original message @harold because I coudn't write it nicely in this answers. I will be updating it there... if it allows me!

Comment: @fauvent Sure that's a start, but I'd switch those loops (for locality of reference). Now just pre-multiply the coordinates where you GetPixel from by some transformation matrix (and watch the bounds) then you're already halfway

Comment: I think I will search for another solution a library or something, because is taking me for ever search information and literaly, learn to program c#. Anyway I appreciate very much your help.